# Facebook login in javascript with php confirmation

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I was looking some questions very similar to mine, but still lost in space here. I got no problems with JS part. I do the login and got my token. Now I need to send http request to a php that will perform queries in the database. How can I trust in a client request? I think I must have a confirmation of the user in server-side. So I taken the php SDK:

EDIT: This is the updated code, it's now working. The $fbToken in obtained by JavaScript and passed to php by Ajax request. Not using FacebookSession yet, baby steps...

```
$Login = ($_SESSION["Login"])? $_SESSION["Login"] : (object)array("ativo"=>FALSE, "metodo"=>"", "id"=>-1, "nome"=>"", "tipo"=>"", "publico"=>"", "nLogin"=>0, "captcha"=>"") ;
//
$fbPhpUser = FALSE;
require $Amb->phpBib.'Facebook/autoload.php'; 
//use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
//FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('{myAppCode}', '{myAppSecret}');
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '{myAppCode}',
  'app_secret' => '{myAppSecret}',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.3',
  ]);
try {
  // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
  $response = $fb->get('/me?fields=id,name', $fbToken);
  $fpPhpUser = $response->getGraphUser();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  fim("fbGraph", 'Erro Facebook Graph: ' . $e->getMessage());
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  fim("fbSDK", 'Erro Facebook SDK: ' . $e->getMessage());
  exit;
}
if($fpPhpUser){
    $Login->ativo = true;
    $Login->metodo = "fb";
    $_SESSION["Login"] = $Login;
}
```

The idea is to get a confirmation that the user is logged and Facebook has authorized my app, so '{access-token}' will be sent by post http request from client browser altogether with the rest of data (e.g.: user register form to be modified on my website database). $Login->ativo==TRUE means I can safely perform database queries. (the user can also login by my own website login system, but I wish he do by Facebook for an integration)
Not sure if will work and a bit tired of to try… Is this the right approach?

Comment: Hi Gustavo, what do you mean with "How can I trust in a client request?". As far as I know, the access token should be enough, if you get that using JS SDK the only thing you should do is an ajax request to your backend to store the access token. Then, you can use PHP or whatever you want to query the database. I'm not really getting the "confirmation" part but I don't think you need that.

Comment: The problem I see is the JavaScript code is open, so I can see the filename of the php script will do the query, as any other php script called by ajax request. I can send a fake token to be stored and perform the queries I want! The only way I can see as safe is to pick this token and check it with Facebook directly from server before perform queries. If you know another way, please answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

You only need the Javascript SDK to accomplish this. Your authorization is obtained through the `statusChangeCallback` function:

```
if (response.status === 'connected') {

    //Logged into FB and app...

} else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {

    //Have NEVER logged into the app before.... you will see permissions page...

} else {

    //NOT logged into FB... so not sure if logged into app...
}
```

Once you are connected, pass the access token via AJAX to your server and do whatever you want with it.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web#checklogin

Comment: Don't think you read my question: "I got no problems with JS part".

Comment: Obviously you don't speak english "You don't need the PHP SDK"

Comment: That's depend on the level of security needed. How the server can know if the token sent by Ajax is real? The server need some base of comparison to decide if the client is really the one authorized by Facebook. I'm beginning to understand why so many servers are hacked every day...